# Firestore SDK - Where does onSnapshot event listener/pending writes store data?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

As per the answer in the link below:
[Does Firebase Firestore keep a local copy of snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71014158/does-firebase-firestore-keep-a-local-copy-of-snapshot)

> The Firestore SDK keeps a local copy of:
>
> - All data that you have an active listener for.
> - All pending writes.
>
> In addition, if offline persistence is enabled,
> it also keeps a local copy of data that
> your code has recently read.

Does this mean that even if offline persistence is disabled on the web, onSnapshot event listeners and pending writes will still be stored locally to cache regardless?

I'm worried about sensitive data on shared computers for these listeners and pending writes that's stored locally (if they did not successfully write to the server, i.e. went offline in the process, etc.). Can malicious users access this data somehow? Is this a flaw of firestore for web apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If offline persistence is disabled, only pending writes are stored in the local cache.

You should assume that all data that is entered on the local device can be intercepted by a malicious actor who gets access to that device. If that is not acceptable for your use-case, consider not using a Firebase SDK for Firestore but using the REST API or gRPC API directly.

Comment: Hello, thanks for confirming! Does this also mean that data with active listeners will also be stored in local cache with offline persistence disabled or will onSnapshot not function with offline persistence disabled?

Comment: If offline persistence is disabled, only pending writes are stored in the local cache. Listeners will only be kept in memory in that case.